# Filepicker.io convert external URL

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I'm using filepicker.io to get a user our users to select an image to an item, we then use the [convert](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/javascript_api/#convert) to make a set of images used for different parts of our applications -- different resolutions and such. We use S3 for storage.

I'm now building a tool for us to adjust the differently scaled images afterwards, as in how to crop the image and where. I've built the tool using JCrop and I get the rectangle to crop using the convert. Fine, I thought, now just let's use the `convert` method to apply the transformation.

However, I can't find a way of using my S3-stored image (i.e. just a URL) to be converted through filepicker.io -- is this possible, if so, how?

We don't store any reference to original Filepicker inkblob.. and the Inkblob doesn't seem to support URLs outside of Filepicker... and I can't find a way of `pickAndStore`-ing an external URL.

Thankful for any idea of approaching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to convert external links with filepicker.

First you have to create filepicker type link. 
For external links the best method would be filepicker.storeUrl()
Then you can convert results.

```
filepicker.storeUrl(
  "https://filepicker_static.s3.amazonaws.com/37e3769/img/landing/cloud.png",
  {filename: 'cloud.png'},
  function(Blob){

    console.log(JSON.stringify(Blob));

    filepicker.convert(
          Blob,
          {
            width: 200,
            height: 200
          },
          function(converted_Blob){
            console.log(new_Blob.url);
            result.src = new_Blob.url;
          }
        );

  }
);
```

Comment: I was retarded/blind yesterday, couldn't find any way of storing an external URL in the API docs. Mondays. THANK YOU!